# Some (specific) domains will not return an HTTP response (not even an error) and browser times out

Tags: google-chrome, http, networking, browser, postman

here's some more context:
(for me, linkedin.com and medium.com are not loading and experiencing these errors)

I have tried:

- restarting my computer (Mac, latest macOS)
- fresh installing Chrome (problem exists on all browsers on this mac)
- disabling all Chrome extensions
- resetting the router in my house

My roommate is not having issues with their computer (for any domain). My phone is connected to the same WiFi network and the pages loaded fine. I ran a simple request via Postman to try and gain some more insight: `GET https://www.medium.com`. The full page of HTML was returned with a code of 200.



Here is the Network output for the request to medium.com in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Here is the response tab:
[image]

In these cases, Chrome is throwing an `ERR_TIMED_OUT` error after 30s without a response.


Here's what I was able to see using Postman:
[image]

And using the preview tab:
[image]

I hope this isn't too far off-topic, any help is much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to have been an OS issue, where mine was trying to force IPv6 for browser traffic. I disabled IPv6 by running `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi` in the terminal. Issue is completely gone, now. Thanks to Michael if you're reading this!